# I am looking for machine vision ways to detect the boxes to allow for the automation of these splits images

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, box

I need help! I am looking for machine vision ways to detect the boxes to allow for the automation of these splits [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2gmw.jpg) every box.
I tried many ways but I can't detect the grid/corner properly.

I need help, how I can do this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MatchTemplate function with the below template image.
[image]

After detecting all matching points with the template image, you can determine the corners of the each box.

Comment: it's a fair approach